# Skoda Fabia, flashes handbrake light and beeps 3 times

Tags: brakes, brake-fluid, skoda

When I turn heavy or accelerate hard in my Skoda Fabia the handbrake light flashes approximately 5 times and beeps exactly 3 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brake fluid was running low, during heavy acceleration or turning the fluid will roll away from the sensor, which created the warning.

I topped up with DOT4 brake fluid and the problem has been resolved.

Do not shake the Brake fluid you do not want bubbles dispersed in you brake fluid.

Comment: 1 more day, till I can.

Comment: I had the same issue (leaking rare pipes), Note that the beep is distinct (louder and high pitch) from the normal beeps like belt, handbrake etc.